# Dimensional Modeling: same degenerate dimension in multiple fact table or using conformed dimension

Tags: dimensional-modeling, degenerate-dimension

I have a retail sales system and want to create a data warehouse using Dimensional Modeling by ralph kimball.

I have a simple `order fact table` that measures `order quantity` and `order dollar amount`. From what I read in the book and internet, the `order number` is a **degenerate dimension** that sits on the fact table.

The `order fact table` then has a `status` that initially I thought it's a flow, so **accumulated snapshot fact table** is come to my mind. It was all fine until I realize the `status` is actually not a flow, it's a label so the order can change status from 'a' to 'b' then to 'a' again. My case is even worse because the `order fact table` is now has 3 types of status that its changes need to be tracked. So I think **accumulated snapshot fact table** is not working here.

My attempt is I create 4 fact tables, `order` `order status a` `order status b` `order status c`.
Every new order creates a row in `order` table as well as one row for initial status in each `order status`. Then every change to the status is done by creating a new row in `order status`.

Since the `order status` table is related to the `order` table, I need these 3 `order status` tables to have reference to the `order` table. How to do it? is using the same `order number` (**degenerate dimension**) suffice? I think of **conformed dimension** also can solve this, but these dimension rows will grow as much as `order` table. Any thought on this?

Comment: Please can you explain what your fact table is measuring, state the grain of your fact table and also explain why the order status changing affects the fact

Comment: The order table is measuring the quantity and dollar amount, while the other 3 status table is more like a factless fact table that measures the total order that has which status. The grain for the order table is 1 row per order while the other 3 status table is 1 row per status change.